# JQuery and frame(set)s - why do they disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frames, frameset

When I use the console and I try to create an element with tag frameset, I get no result:

```
$('<div id="content" data-something="hello" />')
=> [<div id=​"content" data-something=​"hello">​</div>​]
$('<frameset frameborder="0" framespacing="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" framespacing="0" border="0"></frameset>')
=> []
```

This behaviour persists across multiple JQuery versions (like 1.10.2, 2.0.0 and 1.2.6 etc.)

How can I read the 'frameborder' (for example) attribute from this frameset without having to build a parser by mself?

P.S. (If you wonder why I use frames) This line (or a line like this) is a response from an external (more or less) API that I cannot change. I would just like to read the information and go on.

Comment: `<frameset>` can only be a root-level element.  Consider parsing as XML.

Comment: It looks like it only fails with attributes; no clue why.

Comment: Looking further, omitting the attributes makes jQuery use a fast path that calls `createElement()` directly, which succeeds.  The slow path, calling `buildFragment()`, fails.

Comment: Root cause: `var e = document.createElement('div'); e.innerHTML= '<frameset></frameset>'; e;` remains an empty element.

Comment: Unfortunately this API is so obsolete/broken/badly coded, I can't even parse it as XML because it uses the 'framespacing' attribute twice. A workaround that I might consider is simply replacing 'frame' with 'xyz' and hoping it won't affect anything but the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround:

```
var sourceWithFrames = ...
sourceWithFrames = sourceWithFrames.replace(/<frame/g, '<xyzFrame')
// e.g. 
var frameborder = $(sourceWithFrames).find('xyzFrameset').attr('frameborder')
// and so on
```

This is, in my opinion, the best way to approach this (and probably the only one...)

Comment: This workaround approach uses regex indirectly to search for and replace an undesired substring, so that a few more functions can be used to eventually find the desired substring. A regex could be used directly to find the desired substring in one line, like so: 
var frameborder = sourceWithFrames.match(/frameborder="(.+?)"/)[1]

Comment: The problem with this approach, Boric, is that I would not be able to use CSS selectors on the frames and thus could not descend down to possible other frames, or select a frame with a specific attribute and read another attribute from that frame. E.G. if I wanted a selector `$('frame[frameborder=0]').attr('width');`, how would I do this with your approach? I prefer my workaround because while it is a dirty hack, it still leaves me the comfortness of jQuery and not having to write a parser.

Answer (score 1):

The `frameset` tag is to be used as the body of framed documents *in place of the `body` tag*, and in conjuction with the [`frameset` document type declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/framesetdtd.html). It is [considered obsolete since HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#frames).

---

To solve your issue, your best bet is to parse the portions you require from the string on your own or use an HTML parsing library such as [htmlparser.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/)

Comment: While I appreciate your post, my question was more directed to the issue of 'working around' this problem than the answer of why this happens, although of course it is still a good thing to know. Thank you, to review my own workaround solution, here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19825193/1527244

Comment: @Danyel yeah I apologize, I had an edited version waiting here and I simply didn't save it before leaving.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes on your frameset element are not valid HTML, so jQuery does not create it. It will work if you take them out. You can then add the attributes one at a time using `.attr`.

```
var x = $('<frameset></frameset>');
x.attr('frameborder', '0');
x.attr('framespacing', '0');
x.attr('border', '0');
```

But the added code and resource cost of creating an element is not necessary just to find an attribute value in the string. You can find the substring you are looking for with the match method like this:

```
var frameborder = '<frameset frameborder="0" border="0"></frameset>'.match(/frameborder="(.+?)"/)[1]
```

Just replace 'frameborder' in the regex with the name of another attribute to get its value. Simple.

Comment: to be clear, the browser doesn't create it, not jquery. jQuery just passes it along to the correct browser method.

Comment: I said I didn't want to write my own parser. This is essentially doing that. I have submitted an answer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19825193/1527244. I will go with this solution.